# Dictionaries with numpy - Can I use XY coordinates as a hash?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, hash

I have a numpy matrix representing a map of XY coordinates:

```
n = [[0,0],[2,5],[3,1]]
```

Each coordinate is connected to a number of other coordinates, for example:

```
[0,0]:[5,2],[3,7]
[2,5]:[1,4]
[3,1]:[3,7],[5,2],[4,4]
```

My question is, how can I store this information in a convenient dataset?  My gut intuition is to use a dictionary, but I cannot use a numpy array [X, Y] as a hash.  I could convert it to a string, but was wondering if there was a better alternative that I wasn't seeing.

Input would be appreciated!